# I'm trying to embed an image through using binding on xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

So basically I am trying to embed an image to a collection view data template through using binding, as I want each cell to have a different image depending on the path.
I am following this tutorial: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVpbklb6vDc"

However, on that video the woman had hardcoded the path in xaml, whereas I'm trying to databind the path.

recipes.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="CUapp.Recipes"
    Title="Recipes"
    BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CUapp;assembly=CUapp"
    xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Sharpnado.MaterialFrame;assembly=Sharpnado.MaterialFrame">
<StackLayout x:Name="stack" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
    <SearchBar TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged"
               BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
               TextColor="Black"
               PlaceholderColor="DarkGray"
               CancelButtonColor="Red"
               Placeholder="recipe name"
               ></SearchBar>

    <SearchBar BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
               TextChanged="labelSearch_TextChanged"
               TextColor="Black"
               PlaceholderColor="DarkGray"
               Placeholder="labels *seperate with commas*"
               ></SearchBar>
    <Label x:Name="console"></Label>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding recipes}"
                    BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                    Margin="0,10,0,0" HeightRequest="10000"
                    x:Name="collectionView"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    
                    SelectionChanged="collectionView_SelectionChanged">

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="0,0,0,30">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">                        
                            <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <rv:MaterialFrame AcrylicGlowColor="Gray" LightThemeBackgroundColor="LightGray"  WidthRequest="800" HeightRequest="100" Style="{StaticResource AcrylicFrame}" Margin="10,0,10,0" >
                        <Image Source="{local:ImageResource {Binding buttonImg}}"/>

                    </rv:MaterialFrame>
                    <Label Text="{}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Label>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>


    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

recipe.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CUapp

{
    public partial class Recipes : ContentPage
    {

    public ObservableCollection<recipeModel> recipes { get; set; }

    public List<recipeModel> searchBarFilteredItems;
    public List<recipeModel> labelSearchFilteredItems;

    public Recipes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        recipes = new ObservableCollection<recipeModel>(recipeList.list);
        BindingContext = this;

    }

    private async void collectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as recipeModel;
        var view = sender as CollectionView;
        if (view.SelectedItem != null)
        { 
            Navigation.PushAsync(new recipePage(a));
            view.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }

    void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var searchTerm = e.NewTextValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
        {
            searchTerm = string.Empty;
        }

        searchTerm = searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant();

        searchBarFilteredItems = recipeList.list.Where(value =>
        value.title.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchTerm)).ToList();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
        {
            searchBarFilteredItems = recipeList.list.ToList();
        }

        if (labelSearchFilteredItems == null)
        {
            foreach (var value in recipeList.list)
            {
                if (searchBarFilteredItems.Contains(value) == false)
                {
                    recipes.Remove(value);
                }
                
                else if (!recipes.Contains(value))
                {
                    
                     recipes.Add(value);
                    
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var value in recipeList.list)
            {
                if (searchBarFilteredItems.Contains(value) == false)
                {
                    recipes.Remove(value);
                }
                else if (labelSearchFilteredItems.Contains(value) && !recipes.Contains(value))
                {
                    recipes.Add(value);
                }

            }
    
        }
        
    }

    

    void labelSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var searchTerm = e.NewTextValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
        {
            searchTerm = string.Empty;
        }

        searchTerm = searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant();

        char[] seperator = new char[] { ' ', ',' };

        var labelsInSearch = searchTerm.ToString().Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        labelSearchFilteredItems = recipeList.list.Where(value =>
        methods.stringListContains(value.labels,labelsInSearch)).ToList();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
        {
            labelSearchFilteredItems = recipeList.list.ToList();
        }


        if (searchBarFilteredItems == null)
        {
            foreach (var value in recipeList.list)
            {
                if (!labelSearchFilteredItems.Contains(value))
                {
                    recipes.Remove(value);
                }
                else if (!recipes.Contains(value))
                {
                    recipes.Add(value);
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            foreach (var value in recipeList.list)
            {
                if (labelSearchFilteredItems.Contains(value) == false)
                {
                    recipes.Remove(value);
                }
                else if (labelSearchFilteredItems.Contains(value) && !recipes.Contains(value))
                {
                    recipes.Add(value);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

recipeList.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace CUapp
{
    public class recipeList
    {
        public readonly static List<recipeModel> list = new List<recipeModel>
        {
            new recipeModel { i = 1, title = "Spag. Meatballs", labels = { "pasta", "meat" },
                buttonImg = "CUapp.images.spag_meatball_a.jpeg",

            ingredients = {
                new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 3 stalks of celery", color = "#bfe082", glowColor = "#caed8a"  },
                new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 5 heads of brocolli", color = "#90e082", glowColor = "#a3ff91" },
                new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 1 box of spaghetti" }

            },
            howto =
            {
                new ingredientBlock { step = "1.", i = "\tIn a large pot of boiling salted water, cook spaghetti according to package instructions. Drain.", color = "#bfe082", glowColor = "#caed8a"  },
                new ingredientBlock { step = "2.", i = "\tIn a large bowl, combine beef with bread crumbs, parsley, Parmesan, egg, garlic, 1 teaspoon salt, and red pepper flakes. Mix until just combined then form into 16 balls.", color = "#90e082", glowColor = "#a3ff91" },
                new ingredientBlock { step = "3.", i = "\tIn a large pot over medium heat, heat oil. Add meatballs and cook, turning occasionally, until browned on all sides, about 10 minutes. Transfer meatballs to a plate." },
                new ingredientBlock { step = "4.", i = "\tAdd onion to pot and cook until soft, 5 minutes. Add crushed tomatoes and bay leaf. Season with salt and pepper and bring to a simmer. Return meatballs to pot and cover. Simmer until sauce has thickened, 8 to 10 minutes." },
                new ingredientBlock { step = "5.", i = "\tServe pasta with a healthy scoop of meatballs and sauce. Top with Parmesan before serving." }
            },
        },

        new recipeModel { i = 2, title = "Pizza Margherita", labels = { "pizza", "vegetarian" },
                        ingredients = {
                            new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 13 stalks of celery" },
                            new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 15 heads of brocolli" },
                            new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 11 box of spaghetti" }
                        }
        },

        new recipeModel { i = 3, title = "Pantry Pasta With Vegan Cream Sauce", labels = { "pasta", "vegetarian" },
                        ingredients = {
                            new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 113 stalks of celery" },
                            new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 115 heads of brocolli" },
                            new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 111 box of spaghetti" }
                        }
        },

        new recipeModel { i = 4, title = "Burgers", labels = { "meat" },
                        ingredients = {
                            new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 1113 stalks of celery" },
                            new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 1115 heads of brocolli" },
                            new ingredientBlock { i = "   - 1111 box of spaghetti" }
                        }
        }
    };

    public static Dictionary<int, recipeModel> favorites = new Dictionary<int, recipeModel>();

}
}
```

buttonImg is a string.

However when I run the code I get this error:

Error XFC0009: No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Source", or mismatching type between value and property.

Why can't I bind buttonImg to 'Source'?

Any help is deeply appreciated :D

Comment: Have you looked at setting your binding context?

Comment: https://youtu.be/Or_qn8i8jVM

Comment: @AndrewTruckle yea, I set binding context to this in the codebehind of recipe.xaml. It shouldn't be a problem because I could successfully bind other variables to stuff in xaml such as label texts. I've included my recipe.xaml.cs now as well :D

Answer (score 1):

Thx for the answers, but I have found a solution to my problem.

Basically, this was all I did.

```
<Image Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.RowSpan="1">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <FileImageSource File="{Binding buttonImg}" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
```

I didn't need to create any new files/classes, and buttonImg is a string.

The photo is also inside here *proj_name*.images  <-- a folder.

I am very confused as to why people are making this out to be extremely confusing and difficult, creating classes and shit when you really don't need to.

Comment: I think this approach works if you put your image resources on each platform.If you want to put the image resource in shareproject,you need to set its `BuildAction` to `Embedded resource` and convert the string to `ImageSource` like above.The reason why using `StringToImageSourceConverter` is a better way to handle the `buttonImg`,for example,if the buttonImg is not a complete path (like `spag_meatball_a.jpeg`)，then we could construct the complete path in the `StringToImageSourceConverter` method(like `CUapp.images.spag_meatball_a.jpeg`).Of course, the above methods are correct and can be used

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in recipes.xaml

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource {Binding buttonImg}}"/>
```

to this

```
<Image Source="{Binding buttonImg}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Embedded images` with the string `buttonImg`.You could define an [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to convert the `string` to `ImageSource`,then bind it to `Image`.

Create **StringToImageSourceConverter**:

```
class StringToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return ImageSource.FromResource((string)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

then in your xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:StringToImageSourceConverter x:Key="stringToImageSource" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

......

   <rv:MaterialFrame AcrylicGlowColor="Gray" LightThemeBackgroundColor="LightGray"  WidthRequest="800" HeightRequest="100" Style="{StaticResource AcrylicFrame}" Margin="10,0,10,0" >
       <Image Source="{Binding  buttonImg, Converter={StaticResource  stringToImageSource}}"/>

   </rv:MaterialFrame>
......
```